# How to resolve "EmptyDataError" when uploading ".csv" file in colab?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, google-colaboratory

I downloaded a pandas dataframe as a "csv" file in colab and tried to read it in another "ipynb" file in colab.

I used this code to read:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Final/class.csv')
```

I received the following error:

```
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7c4cdcf27eef> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Final/class.csv')
      2 data

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Comment: _I used this code to upload:_ Can you confirm what you actually did? That code wouldn't upload anything, much to the contrary, it would just read a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

1) are you sure that you connect your google drive to notebook?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

2) does file contain any data? please share the example file...